# comma decimal seperator in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, globalization

im desperately trying to make asp.net work with the comma symbol as the decimal seperator but this seems to be a lot harder then necessary...

i've done everything that's in this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

tried this in the root web config

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="de-DE" uiCulture="de-DE" />
</system.web>
```

stepped through the jQuery code - the globalization there seems to work.

i'm using a get request with a model view Controller that looks like this

```
public class SearchCalcViewModel
{
        public SearchCalcViewModel() { }

        public IEnumerable<Calculation> Calculations { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name="Height")]
        public decimal? Height { get; set; }
}
```

the get request is called in the in the maincontroller - so that strengthens my assumption that the jquery culture dependent validation is working and something in the .net culture is awry even though Thread.CurrentTHread.CurrentCulture / CurrentUICulture is set correctly too.

When i try to fill in 3,0 as a height I get the following error message:

The value '3,0' is not valid for Height.

This is the import part of my view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Main", FormMethod.Get))

<div class="form-group">
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Height, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Height, new { @class = "form-control"})
             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Height)
        </div>
     </div>
}
```

this is my MainController:

```
public ActionResult Search(SearchCalcViewModel searchViewModel)
    {
        searchViewModel.Products = db.Products;
        searchViewModel.Calculations = from c in db.Calculations select c;


        if (searchViewModel.Height.HasValue)
        {
            searchViewModel.Calculations =  searchViewModel.Calculations.Where(c => c.Length == searchViewModel.Height);
        }


        return View(searchViewModel);
    }
```

i've stepped into the modelstate and somehow the culture is different from my current culture

[image: wrong culture]

Comment: What is the issue you having. Are you getting a client side validation error (and the form is not submitting)

Comment: as i said the get request is called in my controller so as far as i know it can't be a client side validation error? correct me if im wrong

Comment: So what is the problem? - you have not shown your view or your controller methods or indicated where your error (is there one?) occurs. What is your  actual question?

Comment: i edited my original question to be more clear

Comment: Can you temporarily disable client side validation (in the view add `@ { HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false; HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false; }` to confirm this is a server side issue.

Comment: disabled - and still not working.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. Do you have any custom model binders?

Comment: no i do not! the problem is i don´t know how to debug the default model binder, so i can find out why the parsing isn't working ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82403/discussion-between-raphi011-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value is `3,0` which is not a valid decimal type value. It should be `3.0` replace `" comma(,) with dot(.)`.

Edit : Create your own model binder.

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        return valueProviderResult == null ? base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) : Convert.ToDecimal(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue);

    }    
}
```

Add these lines in Application_Start file.

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

I think this should work now. :)

Comment: it is in germany / austria. this is a localization issue.

Comment: that means you want to accept the value as 3,0.. Ryt?? Then please see my edit now.. May this help up.

Comment: weird that this doesn't work out of the box ... but thanks for the answer! i was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I know is old but I had the same problem (with es-AR) and I found a better solution, you can simple do this:

```
void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Session["userCulture"]);
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(HttpContext.Current.Session["userCulture"]);
}
```

On Global.asax

This code runs before model binding so you can set the culture information to the thread and also you have access to the session variable (for especific user culture)

Comment: You are switching languages on every request made to your app if you do that.