# ASP .NET MVC 5 - decimals always zero in controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015

I'm developing an ASP .NET MVC 5 application in Visual Studio 2015.
I have a simple model created:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

and standard, Visual Studio-added controller and a view. Of course I have a problem with Price decimal field. While trying to add/edit an existing Article, when I type decimal as for instance `5,45` I got an validation error `The field Price must be a number.`. If I type it as `5.45` I don't get this error, however after submitting the form in my controller `Price` property of the Article is set to 0 all the time.
I explored the web and forums and according to [this post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31229332/comma-decimal-seperator-in-asp-net-mvc-5) created the model binder for decimals as:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        return valueProviderResult == null ? base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) : Convert.ToDecimal(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue);

    }
}
```

and then in my `Global.asax.cs` file I put two lines to add this binder for `decimals`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();

        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
        ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
    }
```

However, I still have the same issues, nothing changed.

I also tried to enforce the culture of my PC by putting the following snippet into my `Web.config` file (as advised in [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view)):

```
<system.web>
<globalization culture ="en-US" />
<!--elements removed for clarity-->
```

but it's all the time the same issue :(.
Can you please help me with that? I suppose I'm missing something, but I followed all possible solutions 10 times already and it's still the same...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make sure `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue` it return decimal not integer.

Comment: What is weird it the fact that if I put an breakpoint in my BindModel method in DecimalModelBinder and goes to web page trying to edit or add a new article with Price property filled, this code never gets executed... So I guess there is a problem with adding this Binder to default binders... but I have no idea what could this be.

Comment: I think you haven't read their answer (from your shared link). "Your value is 3,0 which is not a valid decimal type value. It should be 3.0 replace " comma(,) with dot(.)."

Comment: I wrote that as Price I put "5.45", so the format is OK, it uses dot, not commas, but the value of Price is 0 all the time.

Comment: then share your code by which you are posting data from view to controller or controller to view.

Comment: Eh, actually you were right! bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue provided integers, so I modified it to return decimals and it's OK now :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should implement `IModelBinder`:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
        .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e) {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

Then in your `Global.asax.cs`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the issue was the same - I just had wrong BindModel method which returned int instead of decimal. But your solution works as well ;).